# sort PageDataCollection var based on Tree View

Tags: sorting, episerver

I've a function in C# that returns a PageDataCollection variable. 
How can I sort this PageDataCollection based on the Episerver Tree View? (the pages are shown in the tree view in a certain order)
I use Episerver 6 R2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **PageChildOrderRule** property to check the *sort setting* (e.g. by index, publish date, etc) and the **PagePeerOrder** to get the *sort index* (numeric value used if sort order is set to index).

In other words, each page sets how its children are sorted. This in turn is how the page tree is rendered.

These properties are retrieved through the **Property** indexer on your PageData object, for example:

```
int sortIndex = (int)CurrentPage["PagePeerOrder"];
```

Comment: Thank you, Ted! So does this work if I want my PageDataCollection to follow the same sorting applied to the tree view (not the other way around)? `I am working with foreach (PageData x in DataFactory.Instance.FindPagesWithCriteria(rootPage, criterias))
            {
                x["PagePeerOrder"] is not working here? 
            }  ` I want to, based on your idea, first check the PagePeerOrder and then use that info to add the items in another PageDataCollection that I return from the method.

Comment: I haven't used CMS6 for a very long time, but what about FilterSort? https://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6/html/M_EPiServer_Filters_FilterSort_Sort.htm